# Do create View passing Activity as Context cause memory leak?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("some text");
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

We have two objects: one instance of `MainActivity` and  one instance of `TextView` and both of them have reference to each other. So basically it will cause the memory leak. Am I right?

Comment: *Am I right?* No ..

Comment: How did you know its causing memory leak?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi there is both way reference between two objects. So GC can't release anyone of them.

Comment: *So GC can't release anyone of them.* Yes, it can ... TextView is only referenced by Activity ... so obviously if Activity is no longer needed GC is free to free TextView too ... the problem would be if `private TextView textView;` would be `private static TextView textView;`

Comment: @Selvin Could you explain How can it?

Comment: @Selvin `protected Context mContext;` the context is a property of `TextView` which now is `Activity`. So how can GC free `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a question related to `garbage collection algorithms`

What you are thinking is [Reference counting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) . As you are saying, it has some problem with the `circular reference` situation. So it is not used in modern JVMs anymore.

You should check out other garbage collection algorithms and see how modern JVM gc works.

https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/